# Azure AD Connect issue when "mail" and "UserPrincipalName" are different

Tags: azure-active-directory

These are the steps to replicate the issue:

- Customer creates a user in Active Directory with upn "userNameInAd@localdomain.com", *where "localdomain.com" is not registered as custom domain in Azure*
- Customer in Active Directory adds a value to the "mail" attribute for to this user: "personalEmail@whatever.com". *Please note that the names before the "@" in mail and upn are different*
- ADConnect syncs user to Azure AD

In the above conditions, the part before the "@" in the user's UPN in Azure AD is taken from the "mail" attribute in AD instead of from the "UPN" attribute. So, it is:

```
personalEmail@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com
```

For all users synched without "mail" in AD, the name in the UPN in Azure AD is taken from the "UPN" attribute in AD. So, it is:

```
userNameInAd@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com
```

This behavior seems consistent (it is easy to reproduce it) so apparently it is by-design.

Is there a way to force Azure AD to maintain the AD's UPN part before the "@" instead of using the AD's "mail" value?

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior but if you want to change it you have to customize default sync rules.

create a separate rule with lower priority and it is not recommended to change the default rules.

Get detailed information from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-change-the-configuration%20-%20you%20%20can%20get%20the%20detailed%20information%20from%20here%20.)